# How do you disable Cross-Origin-Policy for iframes in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cors, cross-domain

I am running my chrome instance with the --user-data-dir="folder" --disable-web-security flags, but apparently the cross origin policy is still being enforced.   I can't access the elements of an iframe that's from another domain.

Is there any solution to actually disable the check for a same-origin policy, once and for all? Or is there any browser that can properly do that?